# Any theorems for Input-output or input-state stability for non-asymptotically stable nonlinear systems?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

Update for clarification:

Assume  $\dot{x_1}=f(x_1 , x_2)+ au$

where $x_1$ is asymptotically stable for all bounded values of $x_2$. If $x_2$ is kept bounded, will input-output stability theorem apply for a system with $y=x_1$.

---

Khalil's theorem #5.1 and #5.2 consider systems that need to have asymptotically stable unforced version ($u=0$).

Are there any theorems for a system that its unforced version is neutrally stable?
For example:

\begin{cases}
    \dot{x_1}=f(x_1 , x_2)+ au    & \text{}\\
    \dot{x_2}=bu & \text{}
  \end{cases}

where the unforced system is only neutrally stable.

Can we show small-gain stability and bounds for the output   $ y=x_1$  assuming $u$ is $L_2$ bounded, for example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to conclude anything about stability of such a system without further assumptions because you can find counterexamples even if you consider linear systems only. Take for example

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1&=x_2\\
\dot{x}_2&=-x_1+u\\
y&=x_1
\end{align}
$$

which is neutrally stable since the eigenvalues of its $A$ matrix are $\pm j$. However take
$$
u=\frac{\sin(t)}{t + 1}
$$
and zero initial conditions. Note that $u$ is bounded and smooth on $t\in[0,\infty)$. It is also in $L_2$, as

$$
\begin{align}
\Vert u\Vert_{L_2}^2 &= \int_0^{\infty}u(\sigma)^Tu(\sigma)\text{d}\sigma \\
&= \text{Ci}(2)\sin(2) - \text{Si}(2)\cos(2) + \frac{\pi}{2}\cos(2) \\
&\approx 0.399021 < \infty
\end{align}
$$

which can be verified with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28sin%28t%29%2F%28t+%2B+1%29%29%5E2+dt+from+t%3D0+to+inf). Here $\text{Ci}$ is the cosine integral function and $\text{Si}$ the sine integral function.

Using again Wolfram Alpha, the explicit solution is computed as
$$
y(t)= y_u(t) + y_b(t)
$$
with
$$
\begin{align}
y_u(t)&=-\frac{1}{2} \log(t + 1) \cos(t) \\
y_b(t)&= c_2 \sin(t) + c_1 \cos(t) + \frac{1}{2} \text{Ci}(2 t + 2) \cos(t + 2) + \frac{1}{2} \text{Si}(2 t + 2) \sin(t + 2)
\end{align}
$$
with constants $c_1,c_2$. Note that $y_b(t)$ is bounded because $\text{Ci}$ and $\text{Si}$ are bounded on $[2,\infty)$.

However, $y_u(t)$ is unbounded as the logarithm (although slow) keeps growing forever, so $y(t)$ grows (oscillating) above all bounds.

Comment: You are right about a system with imaginary eigenvalues. But can you specifically create a counter-example if the neutrality come from a zero eigenvalue? 
This way the $L_2 $ bound on $u$ prevents you from making $x_2$ unbounded.

Comment: By neutrally stable I mean a system that is Lyapunov stable, but not asymptotically stable.
The example in my question is one. In the unforced system assume  $x_1$ is asymptotically stable for bounded $x_2$ and $x2=x2_0 $ .

Comment: @HamidMov The counterexample can be made valid even for $L_2$ and bounded $u$, I updated my answer. It still requires two imaginary eigenvalues but is now a valid counterexample even for $L_2$ bounded $u$. Regarding your last comment: Ok, but that is not the full requirement because *additionally* you make restrictions on the linearization of the system (only a zero eigenvalue). I will see if I can find an example for this case, but I would recommend to add all these requirements to your question.